# How keystroke simulated in RPA Tools like Automation Anywhere

Tags: c#, sendkeys, citrix, scancodes, automationanywhere

I'm curious to know how Top RPA tools like AA and UiPath simulate keystroke to the applications. 
I've built a application with use of Keybd_event to simulate keystrokes but i keep facing the issue of scan code parameter of **keybd_event** - as it required to perform keystroke in *Citrix environment.*

```
private void PressKeyVK(int eKeys, bool bHoldKeydown, bool bRelease)
    {
        int lScan, lExtended;

        lScan = MapVirtualKey(eKeys, 1);
        lExtended = 0;
        if (lScan == 0)
            lExtended = (int)KeyBoardEventEnums.KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY;
        lScan = MapVirtualKey(eKeys, 0);

        if (!bRelease)
            keybd_event((byte)eKeys, (byte)lScan, (uint)lExtended, UIntPtr.Zero);
        if (!bHoldKeydown)
            keybd_event((byte)eKeys, (byte)lScan, (uint)KeyBoardEventEnums.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP | (uint)lExtended, UIntPtr.Zero);
    }
```

where as below code works well on citrix environment but have issues with local applications.

```
lScan = MapVirtualKey(eKeys, 1); //flag 1: returns virtual key code of scan code eKeys.
```

If flag 2 is used it works well in local applications but SHIFT , ESC and Function keys not working citrix applications.

Please suggest that how the flag can be used to have this code worked in both citrix and local applications.

API references :

[MapVirtualKey MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646306(v=vs.85).aspx)

[Keybd_event MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646304(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Any hope on this thread?

Answer (score 1):

RPA Tools uses different technology for different layer of application. For Local machines mostly by `SendMessage()` and `PostMessage()` APIs. For thin layer applications such as RDP and Citrix it simulates software keypress similar to `Application.Sendkeys()`.

Comment: `Application.Sendkeys` are not fully compatible with Citrix transparent window clients. in C# `System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("{F4}");` has no effect. Application: IE opened via Citrix XenApp